# Convergence/divergence of this numerical series: $\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus

How to determine the convergence/divergence of a numerical series:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)^n.$$

The Cauchy criterion not providing a solution implies that the D'Alembert criterion will also not work. Are there any other methods that can be attempted?

Comment: Please type your attempt and we can help you with where you are getting stuck. Also photos are not permitted in questions--you will need to type in with some MathJax.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: prove $0\le\sin^2\left[(\pi/n)^n\right]\le4^{-n}$ for $n\ge7$.

Comment: @J.G. Why is that and how do you prove it?

Comment: @ArielFishbein Using $0\le\sin x\le x$ for acute $x$, together with $2\pi<7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### HINT

You could say that $$\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{n})^n\le (\frac{\pi}{n})^{2n}$$ as $$n\to\infty$$ so you'll get that $\begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{\pi}{n})^{2n}\end{align}$ converges $\implies$ $\begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^2(\frac{\pi}{n})^n\end{align}$ converges.

By the direct comparison test.